Facebook Graph API: Unable to find the created A/B Test Campaign in console UI Facebook
I am trying to create A/B test using facebook graph API. The documentation I follow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/split-testing
The documentation mentions following curl command:
curl \
-F 'name="new study"' \
-F 'description="test creative"' \ 
-F 'start_time=1478387569' \
-F 'end_time=1479597169' \
-F 'type=SPLIT_TEST' \
-F 'cells=[{name:"Group A",treatment_percentage:50,adsets:[<AD_SET_ID>]},{name:"Group B",treatment_percentage:50,adsets:[<AD_SET_ID>]}]' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \ https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/ad_studies

I am able to run this command successfully and get the split test ID which has been created, but I am unable to find the created split test:https://www.facebook.com/test-and-learn
The created test is fetch-able through API GET endpoint, but it does not exist on facebook console. Here is the place where I am trying to find it:
My goal is to create facebook ads A/B test through graph API. Is there any other documentation for this? or am I understanding something wrong there?

I have found the solution to this problem:
Use USER_ID instead of BUSINESS_ID
and replace type="SPLIT_TEST_V2"
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<USER_ID>/ad_studies
{
    "name": "new study",
    "description": "description of my study",
    "start_time": 1729843787,
    "end_time": 1730280182,
    "cooldown_start_time": 1729843787,
    "observation_end_time": 1730280182,
    "type": "SPLIT_TEST_V2",
    "cells": [
        {
            //"name": "Group A",
            "treatment_percentage": 50,
            "campaigns": [
                "120212284058530726"
            ]
        },
        {
            //"name": "Group B",
            "treatment_percentage": 50,
            "campaigns": [
                "120212284108390726"
            ]
        }
    ]
   
}

